# How to prevent VS Code from recognizing files under the .cargo directory as Git projects?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, rust-cargo

Why are files under the `.cargo` directory getting recognized as Git projects?

[image: .cargo]

It shouldn't be recognized as Git projects.

Comment: Seems like you want to ignore `.cargo` by using `.gitignore`.

Comment: The default location of `.cargo` is `~/.cargo`. Do you have a Git repository in the root of your home directory?

Comment: see [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a file named as `.gitigonre` in your project folder.
2. Inside the file write `.cargo`.